# Segmentation fault - C++ array

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to change the text of some Labels with the following connections:

```
connect(ui->styleSelector, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setStyle(int)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(instrumentChanged(QString)), ui->label_inst_1, SLOT(setText(QString)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(instrumentChanged_2(QString)), ui->label_inst_2, SLOT(setText(QString)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(instrumentChanged_3(QString)), ui->label_inst_3, SLOT(setText(QString)));
```

My `setStyle` slot:

```
    void SamplerModule::setStyle(int style){
    m_style = style;  
    emit instrumentChanged(m_instruments[m_style][0]);
    emit instrumentChanged_2(m_instruments[m_style][1]);
    emit instrumentChanged_3(m_instruments[m_style][3]);
}
```

And my array (set in my Class constructor)

```
QString m_instruments[3][3];

m_instruments[0][1] = "Trompette";
m_instruments[0][2] = "Basse";
m_instruments[0][3] = "Piano";

m_instruments[1][1] = "Guitare";
m_instruments[1][2] = "Batterie";
m_instruments[1][3] = "Basse";

m_instruments[2][1] = "Basse";
m_instruments[2][2] = "Batterie";
m_instruments[2][3] = "Guitare";
```

But when i'm trying to run the code, I've a segmentation fault because of my signals which use `m_instruments[x][0]`.

I really don't understand why. My slot `setStyle` has the right to access this array, so why this segmentation fault ?

---

Detail:

If i set `QString m_instruments[3][3];` instead of `QString m_instruments[][3];` in my header then the seg fault disappears. **However**, the array appreas empty outside of the constructor.

`qDebug() << m_instruments[0][0];` returns "Trompette" in the consturctor but returns "" in my `setStyle` slot !

Comment: You do know that arrays are 0-indexed, right? So array of size 3 will have elements with indices 0,1 and 2. Accessing element at index 3 in such an array is an error.

Comment: My bad, I tried so many times to edit everything that I forget to set the right index back. It's fixed, but the segmentation fault is still there. :/

Comment: What value is being passed as an argument to the setStyle() slot?  If it's not 0, 1, or 2, then you will be accessing an invalid index in your m_instruments array.

Comment: Can you please the complete body of the constructor as in your code? Specifically, does it actually contain the `QString m_instruments[3][3];` bit? (In effect shadowing the member variable)?

Comment: I've edited the code.
As I only added 3 items to the selector, it should not access an invalid index.

Comment: Please do not radically change the nature of the question after it has been answered. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is still the same. I've just added more information.

Comment: @user There are situations where that advice is appropriate, and situations where it is not. This is the latter. I know it's easy to blindly regurgitate policies you once saw in others' comments or on meta, but it's generally more helpful to think about the situation first.

Comment: Disagree, @JasonC . The problem in the initial cut of the question was an out of bounds array access. That was resolved. OP then changed the question, replacing the out of bounds accesses with in bounds accesses invalidating the existing answer, and added the code that was now triggering the new segfault. I reverted the edit and explained why.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you have listed the following array:

```
QString m_instruments[3][3];
```

This array is length 3x3, which means you can access 3 column elements, 0, 1 and 2. On this line:

```
m_instruments[0][3] = "Piano";
```

You access element *index* 3, which is past the end of the array, which causes *Undefined Behavior* (in your case resulting in seg fault).

This may not be the only problem with your code, but it is certainly one of them.

Comment: My bad, I tried so many times to edit everything that I forget to set the right index back. It's fixed, but the segmentation fault is still there. :/

Comment: @RobinFourcade are you certain it is not somewhere else? Segfaults can be tricky that way, the code breaks something over *there* and finally falls down and dies over *here*.

Comment: Pretty sure, yes! 
As soon as I comment the 3 emits, the fault disappears. And the fault only occurs when I'm changing my index through my selector, and when it tries to access my array.

Comment: @RobinFourcade Ok, but you actually use index `[3]` in two places: You use it when setting `m_instruments` in your constructor, *and* you use it in that third emit. This answer only points out the former so maybe you missed it, but did you fix *both* of those before determining the seg fault was still around? Or did you just tackle one? Also are you *positive* you aren't using index `[3]` elsewhere in other code snippets? And finally, since you made this indexing mistake here, are you *sure* you don't have similar indexing mistakes with other arrays elsewhere? Double check!

Comment: Yep, checked, re-checked and re-re-chechked!
What's strange is that I'm using `qDebug() << m_instruments[0][0];` in the constructor, it works well. But as soon as I call it in `SamplerModule::setStyle`the seg fault happens.

Comment: @jason-c As I added in the question, the array exists but it's just empty outside of the constructor qnd I don't understand why!

Comment: When you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), your program may continue to run for some time after that, until *BOOM* it crashes somewhere else.

Comment: Accessing an array out of bounds is one possible way to invoke it, but there are many others.

Comment: If i set `QString m_instruments[3][3];` in my header and remove it from my constructor (I just fill it in the constructor), then everything works well.
But as I need my first dimension not to be const, I can't let that like that.

Comment: @Robin It sounds to me like you have about a dozen different problems all boiling down to a fundamental failure to understand how to both declare and access arrays properly, esp. multidimensional ones. Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/, read it *thoroughly*, practice a bit if necessary, then reexamine your code and see if you can apply any of the knowledge there. For example your hand wavey attempt to declare the array with a missing `[] ` first index was *very* incorrect, but it's easier for you to look up why then it is for us to give tutorials in language fundamentals.